# Terraform use local provider/plugin

Tags: terraform

I installed **Terraform v1.0.1 on linux_amd64** (**Oracle Linux Srv 8.4 64bit**).

I’m trying to use a local provider/plugin that I saved in the folder: **/root/.terraform.d/plugins**

```
# ll /root/.terraform.d/plugins
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       38 Jun 29 15:42 oldversion
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 30068808 Jun 29 15:42 terraform-provider-zabbix
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       52 Jun 29 15:42 test_plugging
```

This is my **vim /root/.terraformrc**:

```
provider_installation {
  filesystem_mirror {
    path    = "/root/.terraform.d/plugins"
  }
  direct {
    exclude = ["registry.terraform.io/*/*"]
  }
}
```

This is my **main.tf**:

```
terraform {
    required_version    = ">= 0.12.6"
}
provider "zabbix" {
    username            = local.provider_vars.zabbix.username
    password            = local.provider_vars.zabbix.password
    url                 = local.provider_vars.zabbix.endpoint
    tls_insecure        = true
}
```

but when I run: `terraform init`

> Initializing the backend...
>
> Initializing provider plugins...
>
> - Finding latest version of hashicorp/zabbix...
>
> **Error: Failed to query available provider packages**
>
> Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
> hashicorp/zabbix: provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/zabbix was
> not found in any of the search locations
>
> - /root/.terraform.d/plugins

How can fix this problem?
Thanks for the help

Marco

Answer (score 18):

Assuming you have a binary

```
~/.terraform.d/plugins/terraform.local/local/zabbix/1.0.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-zabbix_v1.0.0
```

Configure Terraform as follows

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    zabbix = {
      source  = "terraform.local/local/zabbix"
      version = "1.0.0"
      # Other parameters...
    }
  }
}
```

Which works as follows

```
terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding terraform.local/local/zabbix versions matching "1.0.0"...
- Installing terraform.local/local/zabbix v1.0.0...
- Installed terraform.local/local/zabbix v1.0.0 (unauthenticated)

Terraform has created a lock file .terraform.lock.hcl to record the provider
selections it made above. Include this file in your version control repository
so that Terraform can guarantee to make the same selections by default when
you run "terraform init" in the future.

Terraform has been successfully initialized!
```

Comment: this is still trying to fetch terraform.local host and does not solve the issue exactly.

Answer (score 10):

The solution above is absolutely correct, but needs to be clarified **edit .terraformrc**:

```
provider_installation {
  filesystem_mirror {
    path    = "/home/user/.terraform.d/plugins"
  }
  direct {
    exclude = ["terraform.local/*/*"]
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your comment. I had an issue with the terraform template provider. I managed to compile it with the commands

    brew install kreuzwerker/taps/m1-terraform-provider-helper
    m1-terraform-provider-helper activate
    m1-terraform-provider-helper install hashicorp/template -v v2.2.0
however this did not work without the .terraformrc file

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me. I put my plugin under the below folder. Make sure the third folder after plugins is the name of the provider. In my case kafka-connect.
Also the version is important and the machine architecture.

```
 ~/.terraform.d/plugins/kyma-project.io/kyma-incubator/kafka-connect/0.3.0/darwin_arm64/terraform-provider-kafka-connect_v0.3.0
```

and make sure the binary has executable permissions

Next my provider looked like this.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kafka-connect = {
      source = "kyma-project.io/kyma-incubator/kafka-connect"
      version = "0.3.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "kafka-connect" {
  url = "http://localhost:8083"
}
```